# corona sdks - Why ain't my database updating count?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I seem to be having an issue with my database in corona sdk. I want to store the play counts every time a player plays the game. my project doesn't have a gamescene and plays only through menu.lua. I have set up a highscore database (which is separate from the other one but exactly the same) and it works fine and updates/loads data fine. My play count data base however doesn't work.

At first the play count increases by 1 when the game returns to menu again once its removed. But tries after that doesn't increase the value, it's like it has reset.

Globals.lua

```
M.plays = 0
--------------------------
local function setupDatabase2()
    local dbPath = system.pathForFile("appInfo.db3", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    local db = sqlite3.open( dbPath )   
    local tablesetup1 = [[ 
         CREATE TABLE played (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, plays); 
         INSERT INTO played VALUES (NULL, '0');  
    ]]
db:exec( tablesetup1 ) --Create it now.
db:close() --Then close the database

end
setupDatabase2()

M.loadAppInfo = function()
    local dbPath = system.pathForFile("appInfo.db3", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    local db = sqlite3.open(dbPath)
    for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM played WHERE id = 1") do
        M.plays = tonumber(row.plays)
    end
    db:close()
end

M.saveAppInfo = function()
    local dbPath = system.pathForFile("appInfo.db3", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    local db = sqlite3.open(dbPath)
    local update = "UPDATE played SET plays='" .. M.plays .."' WHERE id=1"
    db:exec(update)
    db:close()
end

return M
```

menu.lua

```
local utils = require("helpers.globals")
local play = 0
----------------------------------------
function scene:createScene( event )
local group = self.view

utils.loadHighscoreInfo() -- Separate db which is working fine 
utils.loadAppInfo()

function beginGame( event )
    timerSrc = timer.performWithDelay(400, createBlock, -1)
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", gameLoop)
    play = play +1
    utils.plays = play
    utils.saveAppInfo()
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL statement is doing all of that. Your current sql creates a table everytime it is called. Try this:

```
 local tablesetup1 = [[ 
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS played (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, plays); 
     INSERT INTO played VALUES (NULL, '0');]]
```

I guess that statement is pretty much self explanatory :)

Comment: Hi JamParaiso, I notice where the problem was. It was with my variable 'Play', it wasn't updating per turn so the count never updated. Thanks for the help, the table is working perfect now!

Comment: Oh I skipped the variable at the top. Glad to help :)